# Make a child as wide as the parent of parent

Tags: html, css, css-position, stylesheet

I have two nested `div`. Outermost nested into `section`.

Is it somehow possible to make innermost `div` as wide as `section`?

Here is my snippet:

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}


#content {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="content">
    <div>
      <p>
        test
      </p>
      <div id="inner">
        <p>
          inner
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, set the width to 100% for the "middle div" & the "inner div"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either have to make one in the middle the same width as well, or use fixed widths/paddings and negative margins.

See the demo below (using negative margin).

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}


#content {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="content">
    <div>
      <p>
        test
      </p>
      <div id="inner">
        <p>
          inner
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Mmmmm... Positioned elements *can* have any size & position

Comment: Just noticed that it was using a fixed padding. Added a solution with demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}


#content {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#content > div {
    width: inherit;
}


#inner {
  width: inherit;
  background-color: pink;
}
```